# How can i call a function and gets its return value? Flutter/Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like the text in the top right to be `Total Members: example` but at the moment I get `Total Members: Instance of 'Future<String>'` and I'm not sure why

My Code:

```
class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Main",
            style: globals.style
                .copyWith(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
      ),
      drawer: MyDrawer(),
      body: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.topRight,
        margin: new EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0, right: 20.0),
        child: Text('Total Members: ' + fetchMainInfo().toString(),
            style: globals.style
                .copyWith(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
      ),
    );
  }
}


Future<String> fetchMainInfo() async {
  return "example";
}
```

I am very new to flutter/dart so I'm sorry if the answer is really obvious but I've done some looking around but can't find anything that seems to work for me and have found some stuff with set state but I'm wondering if there is a similar way to do it as I am very new to dart/flutter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You face this error because you are trying to get data from async method, so to solve this you need futurebuilder.

```
FutureBuilder(
          future: fetchMainInfo(),
          builder: (_, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return Text('Total Members: ${snapshot.data}',
                  style: globals.style.copyWith(
                      color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold));
            } else {
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            }
          }),
```

Answer (score 1):

If your method only returns a `String` and not a `Future`, then you should have that as it's definition. Remove the `Future` and `async` from the method:

```
String fetchMainInfo() {
  return "example";
}
```

Comment: Thank you I didn't even think about that

Comment: If will indeed use a method that will fetch from an url or something similar from a database, then you would have to have an await before the method call, but this implies a few more changes to the code. You could simply call the method on the initState and have a setState change the String variable on the Text widget once it's done.